# direction algorithm based on screen touch coordinates

Tags: algorithms

There is a running object on computer screen. User can move the object up, down, left or right by touching 4 edges on the screen. Given screen coordinate origin(0, 0) at up-left corner, x axis positive to the right, y axis positive down, the touch point coordinates(x, y), a simple algorithm for determining the moving direction could be:

```
    // Normalize x,y between 0 and 1
    float x = touch.getX() / Screen.getWidth();
    float y = touch.getY() / Screen.getHeight();

    // Direction will be [0,1,2,3] depending on 4 quadrants which are divided by 2 diagonal lines
    int direction = 0;
    direction = (x > y) ? 1 : 0;
    direction |= (x > 1 - y) ? 2 : 0;

    // Direction is same as the quadrant which was touched, 0 for left, 1 for down, 2 for up, 3 for right.
```

This algorithm is based on the center point of the screen, and is not ideal. Now it is preferred that user can touch any point(except the object itself) in the screen to determine the moving direction. We want the same algorithm as above but centered with the object instead of the center point of the screen, so that when user touches at left, right, above, below the object, the moving direction would be left, right, up and down respectively. Suppose the object coordinate is (ox, oy). What is the algorithm for determining move direction?